# Select DropDown value Programmatically in angularjs with spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, select

hi I am using spring mvc with angular js. i have a drop down in my edit page. drop down in successfully populated with data. In angular controller i was trying to select an option Programmatically but not succeeded. i was using tempplate injection in angularjs, with that $scope.data=1 is not working.

here is my mode

script.js

```
sampleApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
    $scope.Fruits = [{
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Apple',
        Selected: false
    }, {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Mango',
        Selected: true
    }, {
        Id: 3,
        Name: 'Orange',
        Selected: false
    }];

    $scope.data=1;
});
```

about.jsp

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>About Page</h1>

    <p>{{ message }}</p>

    <select  ng-model="data" ng-options="i.Id as i.Name for i in Fruits">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I am using a route in angularjs to inject about.jsp partial page into index.jsp page.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Your code works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/XgbCYjFFD7UZh8G8v73P?p=preview. Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: There is your problem. That is a much too old version. Plenty of bugs have been fixed since that version, that is almost 3 years old. The current stable version is 1.5.3. Upgrade ASAP.

Comment: Ok. i will try it. Thanks @JBNizet